# Execution order of test cases in Cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, testng

Below is the structure how my Feature Files are divide. I have created Folders based on the functionalities and then added the scenarios inside them.
Now, I have to tag few test cases among them as Smoke Test cases and get them executed.
The point here is I need a specific order for that as in eg

```
Add Asset
Run Test
Schedule Test
Delete Asset
```

Since I will add something first and then work on it and delete it at the end

[image]

I know by default Cucumber executes test cases alphabetically but that would not solve my problem.
How can I achieve that?
I am using Java

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber features/scenarios are run in Alphabetical order by feature file name.

However, if you specifically specify features, they should be run in the order as declared. For example:

```
@Cucumber.Options(features={"automatedTestingServices.feature", "smoketest.feature"})
```

Comment: You're mixing `cucumber-jvm` and `cucumber-js`

Comment: Oops, took out the is-specific links

Comment: Where did you add these cucumber options in your code?  It works for me.  The whole point of the `features` cucumber option is to specify which features should run and in which order.

Comment: I did it in the Runner file as mentioned in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by setting priority or dependency, supported in [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) which is [TestNg implementation for BDD](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#bdd). Setting priority with scenarion should do the needful for example:

with QAF  scenario in `DeleteAssets.feature` may look like below:

```
 @priority:100
 #or you can set dependencies like below
 #@dependsOnGroups:['create','schedule']
 @delete @otherGroup
 Scenario: Delete existing Asset
    Given ...
```

**Note**: gherkin syntax doesn't supports meta-data so you need to use either qaf bdd or bdd2 syntax and appropriate factory to run tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set a priority in cucumber scenarios. but not for the whole scenarios we can do that. inside methods we have declared in step definition file, can achieve that. Just put a keyword **"Order" in the step definition file over the method** based on the order of the method it will run as priority.

[Click here for reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-the-order-of-execution-for-test-methods-in-cucumber)